# How to handle error channel for ExecutorChannel in Spring Integration Java DSL

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl

I would like to know how to limit only the caller handle the error for executor channel in Spring Integration Java DSL.

e.g.
In my use case, I have a `queue` (with a size of 100 to throttle the input) for the caller to send events, the poller will poll the queue and send to an `ExecutorChannel` for async processing (assume the processing is CPU intensive and we limit the pool size of task executor to 2). The result of the async processing will send back to caller. Also, if there is an exception throws for async processing. The original caller will deal with the exception rather than let a global error handler to handle it.

I don't know how to specify a channel that only the caller can see the error thrown from the `ExecutorChannel` and handle it in a private way in Spring Integration Java DSL.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you have to specify `errorChannel` header for some `MessageChannel` which is exactly up to that your caller.

The `ExecutorChannel` is based on the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` which has a code like:

```
private MessageChannel resolveErrorChannel(Throwable t) {
    Message<?> failedMessage = (t instanceof MessagingException) ?
            ((MessagingException) t).getFailedMessage() : null;
    if (this.defaultErrorChannel == null && this.channelResolver != null) {
        this.defaultErrorChannel = this.channelResolver.resolveDestination(
                IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    }

    if (failedMessage == null || failedMessage.getHeaders().getErrorChannel() == null) {
        return this.defaultErrorChannel;
    }
    Object errorChannelHeader = failedMessage.getHeaders().getErrorChannel();
    if (errorChannelHeader instanceof MessageChannel) {
        return (MessageChannel) errorChannelHeader;
    }
    Assert.isInstanceOf(String.class, errorChannelHeader,
            "Unsupported error channel header type. Expected MessageChannel or String, but actual type is [" +
            errorChannelHeader.getClass() + "]");
    return this.channelResolver.resolveDestination((String) errorChannelHeader);
}
```

Pay attention to the part with the `failedMessage.getHeaders().getErrorChannel()`.

The good out-of-the-box solution for your is `@MessagingGateway` with the `errorChannel` option. This one use exactly the same `errorChannel` header technique and let handle or re-throw exception exactly just in the scope of that `@MessagingGateway`.